# send an Image with a cloud-message firebase notification not working

Tags: node.js, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented the notification successfully, but when I pass the image it isn't working for some reason.

Here is my implementation:

```
notification(user.fcmToken, {
    notification: {
      title: title,
      body: message,
      imageURL: "https://.../avatar/avatar1.png",
    },
  });
```

and the notification function:

```
exports.notification = async (registrationToken, message = message_notification, notify_options = options ) => {
   try {
        const response = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(registrationToken, message, notify_options);
        console.log('Notificatin response:', JSON.stringify(response));
        if(response.successCount > 0) {
            return {
                statusMessage: 'SUCCESS',
                message: 'Sent Successfully',
                statusCode: 200,
            }
        }
        if(response.failureCount > 0) {
            return {
                statusMessage: 'ERROR',
                message: 'Falure',
                statusCode: 400,
            }
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error", error)
       return {
        statusMessage: 'ERROR',
        message: 'SERVER ERROR',
        statusCode: 400,
      }
    }
};
```

Comment: What is your expectation?

Comment: to see an image in the notification

Answer (score 0):

You need use the method send or sendAll instead of sendToDevice.
send and sendAll only accept one token string by request

```
     const notificationTokens = ["token1","token2"]
     const params = notificationTokens.map(token => ({
          token: token,
          notification: {
            body: "My TestBody",
            title: "My Title",
            imageUrl: 'http:imageurl.jpg'
          },
          data: {} //optional
        }))
         const response = await admin
        .messaging()
        .sendAll(registrationToken, message, notify_options);
```

if you have only string token you can use send instead send all.

Read the documentation for more information :
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#example-notification-message-image